# How to find out its Nodejs version via a js function?

Tags: node.js

I would like to know the current version of Node, such as the one obtained by the command line "node -v", but via a js function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NodeJS global object property [process.version](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/process.html#process_process_version) might be what you need.

Comment: A global object property, not a function, but yes, that's the way.

Comment: @pawel oops my bad, I'll edit!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! variable or function, it suits me ...

Comment: There is also https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/process.html#process_process_versions